# How does netty determine when a read is complete?

Tags: java, networking, netty, nio

Below is a `ChannelHandler` for a echo server.

[image]

Netty framework will call `channelReadComplete()` method to notify the handler that the last call made to `channelRead()` was the last message in the current batch.

My question is, since data are transferred on wire in trunks, how could Netty know when `a batch of message` is complete?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

channelReadComplete() is triggered once there is no more data to read from the underlying transport. When talking about SocketChannels this would be either of these two cases:

1. read(...) returns 0
2. read(...) got a buffer passed to it that has 1024 bytes to fill, but less than 1024 are filled.

Comment: Thanks. These clear rules are better than some high-level vague description.

Comment: I think channelReadComplete() is also triggered by [Channel.read()](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html#read()) if any data was read, even if more data remains to be read from the underlying transport. @Norman is this correct? If so, any reason behind this behavior? Thanks!

Comment: yes that is correct... the channelReadComplete() only signals that there will be no more read for the Channel in the current even-loop run. So you could for example flush now

Comment: @NormanMaurer this is puzzling, because a socketChannel 
 read length returns 0 does not mean there WILL be no more to read, returns -1 does. How to handle returns -1?

Comment: negative means EOF.